# Почему float: left плохо?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, code-style

Нашел вот такие рекомендации по верстке: https://github.com/delka/html5checklist

Там есть пункт:

--

**Плохо:**

**Самое страшное, к счастью уже редкое — float: left для всех блоков.** Безумный верстальщик эмулирует привычные ячейки таблиц, расставляя блоки как кирпичи друг за другом. Вон из профеcсии! Проверяется: Web Developer Outline → Float elements, если всё в красных блоках, вёрстку нужно выкидывать на помойку.

--

Я довольно часто использую float. Кто-то может объяснить вышеизложенное? Почему float плохо? Что можно использовать вместо него?

Comment: Я незнаю, сам довольно часто использую, и не вижу в этом ничего плохого.

Comment: Скорее всего автор имеет ввиду именно использование `float: left` для ВСЕГО. `* {float: left;}`

Comment: Сомневаюсь, что имеется ввиду `* {float: left;}`... Где такое может вообще понадобиться?

Comment: Переучиваемся на использование Flexible Box Layout Module. [Toster: Почему нельзя задавать float:left всем блокам?](https://toster.ru/q/127615)

Comment: Зачем закрыли? Это ж не опросник...

Comment: Переоткроем.. Не любит что-то народ вопросы по стайл-гайдам.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, "требует для нормальной работы overflow: hidden у контейнера" - неправда.

Comment: обычный .clearfix чем хуже ?

Comment: @PavelMayorov открыли

Answer (score 2):

Ничего плохого.
Есть у некоторых сомнения про производительность, но вроде это совсем неактуально.

Answer (score 1):

Вместо него можно использовать **CSS3 Grid Layout** сеточной модели,
но это уже следующий уровень!

Comment: ... который не поддерживается нигде кроме IE?  
Ну да, конечно можно!

Comment: год назад так говорили про python - "мол нету хостов которые его поддерживают", теперь он стоит даже на бесплатных хостингах...

Comment: @pipin основной вопрос - "Почему float: left плохо" - хотелось бы узнать, почему :)

Answer (score 1):

Если размещаемые блоки случайно окажутся разными по высоте, даже на полпикселя - результат получится очень некрасивый. Альтернативные же решения куда более устойчивы.

Comment: Можно уточнить, какие альтернативные решения более устойчивы?
`inline-block/table/flex` ?  На мой взгляд, всё зависит от контекста использования

Comment: @Olegatro `display: inline-block`, к примеру.

Comment: Если сравнивать `inline-block` и `float`, то проблема разной высоты блоков не решается.  И у `inline-block` и у `float` есть свои недостатки.
У `inline-block` нужно сбрасывать отступы, гор. через `<!-- -->`, верт. через `vertical-align: top/bottom`. У `float`, как правило нужно ставить `clearfix` на родителя.  `inline-block` оправдан, когда нужно выравнить элементы по какой то линии, т.к. будет работать `vertical-align`, в остальных случаях, нужно смотреть на контекст использования. Но я бы не стал говорить, что `inline-block` лучше `float`.

Comment: @Olegatro он и не лучше. Но он устойчивей при бездумном использовании.